# Remove punctuation except a particular symbol in a particular position

Tags: text-processing, tr

I'm using `tr` to parse text and do several tasks like lower-case all words, remove punctuation and multiple spaces. The end result should be clean lower-case text with only alpha-numeric characters, except in a particular case:

```
word$digit
```

such as

```
house$999
```

The formulation excepting this case is very simple. For example, just for the case where I remove punctuation, I would substitute it with a space using

```
tr '[:punct:]' ' '
```

It's just a matter of using pipes to obtain the rest of the desired output. E.g.,

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < $1 | tr '[:punct:]' ' ' | ... > $2
```

However, I'm having some trouble trying to figure out how to define the exception so that a `$` symbol between alphanumeric characters and a group of digits is maintained, while other instances, and all other punctuation symbols, are removed.

Comment: One possibility is to have a `sed` filter that first replaces the `$` by some outlandish character that isn't a punctuation, run your pipe, and then change the outlandish character backback to `$`.

Comment: Is the particular case context-sensitive, that is, should $ only be preserved if it occurs directly between a group of letters and a group of digits? In that case, `tr` is probably not the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the answer from @xenoid, the following code works for me

```
echo -e "Hello.\n;132\$And; Another\$98?';:" | sed -e 's/\([[:alpha:]]\+\)\$\([[:digit:]]\+\)/\1 THIS \2/g' -e 's/[[:punct:]]//g' -e 's/ THIS /$/g' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

The result is:

```
hello
132and another$98
```